# Read excel file with c# in 64-bit pc with Office 2003

Tags: c#, excel

I have a desktop application which has to read an excel file (either .xls or .xlsx).

When the application is installed in a Windows 7 pc with Office 2003 i cant read the excel file using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. I have the message that Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered.
Using Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0. doesnt help either.

So how can we read the excel file? I know one option is to build my application forcing it to compile to (x86) so it runs as a 32-bit application.
Ok, supposing i dont want to do so, is there any other option? 
Thanks for any answers. Any comments are welcome!

Comment: ACE 12 is for both 2007 and 2010. Anything before that is JET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Npoi](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). Stand alone library that can work with xls and xlsx files. No need to use those Jet libraries. 
Ok, that will involve a bit of work, but you remove a dependency from something you can't control on user's machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need the 64-bit JET/ACE driver installed:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Did you even read the blog post? Access 2010 x64 has a 64 bit version of ACE.

Comment: It's probably worth nothing there are limitations on the installation of Office x64. Technet has this info.

Comment: I have already tried it but it gives me the error that i have the following 32bit applications installed: Office 2003, so i cannot install Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable 2010_x64.

Comment: You need may to uninstall office, install the engine redistributable, then reinstall office.

Comment: I see but I dont think that the users of the application will be very happy with this solution!

Comment: Indeed. You're in a slightly awkward position really - the redist I linked is mostly intended for server environments for dealing with legacy systems. Officially what you're trying to do is deprecated. Is the MDB something the user has access to via Access? If not you may want to consider switching to SQL Compact (which can use a local file) instead.